# Struggling with a Type Error on my coding for a basic calculation

Tags: python

I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. I convert my numericals to floats, then use them and declare `bmi` as a float. The problem comes before the print statement in the last line. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

What variable in my code is the console reading as a string?

```
height = input("enter your height in m: ")
weight = input("enter your weight in kg: ")


float(height)
float(weight)
bmi = weight / height ** 2
float(bmi)
print("Your BMI is " + str(bmi))
```

Comment: `float(height)` doesn't modify height in place. Strings are immutable which means they can't be changed in place. You need to manually save it with `height = float(height)`

Comment: And as a side note, `bmi` will already be a float.  You don't have to convert it to anything.

Comment: Very rarely in Python will a function modify a parameter, and in many cases it's simply impossible. This is one of those cases.

Answer (score 2):

what really is happening that the convert value of height and weight are stored anywhere and they remain as strings and so the error

try below

```py
height = float(input("enter your height in m: ")) 
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))
```

you can take input as a float instead of string which will automatically return a float value for bmi while calculating
and it will not give any error also

or else

```
height = float(height) 
weight = float(weight)
```

you can assign float values to var again like above

And also you dont need to convert bmi to float again as bmi will become type float since both var are floats

Comment: thank you all for your comments, new to coding and appreciate that i can get help like this

Answer (score 0):

`float(height)` and `float(weight)` is converting `height` and `weight` into float variables, but it does not save them. So `height` and `weight` are still strings after the conversion, which is why you are getting this error. Also, `bmi` does not need to be converted into a float, because it already is a float. This is what your code should look like:

```py
height = input("enter your height in m: ")
weight = input("enter your weight in kg: ")

# Saves the height and weight variables as floats
height = float(height)
weight = float(weight)

# bmi does not need to be converted into a float,
# because it already is a float since the weight and height
# variables are floats
bmi = weight / height ** 2

print("Your BMI is " + str(bmi))
```